# Ionic2 Ion-select without OK and Cancel

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have built an Ionic2 app and I am currently trying to improve the UX. To do that, I received some feedback that made me think of whether there is a way of having a

```
    <ion-select>
      <ion-option>
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
```

which upon tapped on, would give me the output straight away and not wait for the user to press on the currently appearing 'OK'and 'CANCEL' buttons that the ionic action sheet(http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/) uses by default.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated! :)

**EDIT:**

As @sebaferrreras has suggested,

**If the number of options exceed 6, it will use the alert interface even if action-sheet is passed.**

So if you need to use more than 6 options, you are going to have to find a workaround as for the moment, this functionality is **NOT** **listed** under the **Ionic2 docs**.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @user3153278 I am also struggling in this very mush any updated answer you have

Comment: Unless it's the options you are listing are less than 6, it will be fine, otherwise not at this stage.

Answer (score 10):

Changing the API used in the select element (by using the [ActionSheet API](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/action-sheet/ActionSheet/)) could be an option.

In order to do that, you only need to add `interface="action-sheet"` in the `ion-select` element.

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="action-sheet">
      <ion-option value="f" selected="true">Female</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

I'm not sure if that's a valid option (in terms of UX) in your app.

---

**EDIT:**

Just like you can find in [Ionic 2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/#single-value-radio-buttons)

> If the number of options exceed 6, it will use the alert interface
>   even if action-sheet is passed.

Comment: I am not sure I see your point. Adding the action-sheet interface gives us four options only, none of which seem to be related to my problem. Thank you for your answer thought! :-) @sebaferreras

Comment: What do you mean by 'give us four options only'? Please take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KovVrZ?p=preview). Anyway, it seems that if the options are more than just a few, the select component still uses the Alert API. I will test a few things in that plunker and will update the answer if I find something that could help :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the ActionSheet interface seemed to have 4 methods that could be extended only. And, yes, this is exactly the functionality I am looking for. And what did you mean by "if the options are more than just a few, the select component still uses the Alert API"? The example from plunker has multiple options(perhaps using the Alert API indeed) but lacks both OK and Cancel buttons and selects the option on mouse click.

Comment: Yeap, but if you add just another option to the select element, an alert will be shown. So if this is the functionality you were looking for, I'll just investigate a little bit more about the number of options that could be used with this API, and edit the post with that information.

Comment: Oh, I see! And I will investigate this now and edit the post later if I manage to find a solution. Feel free to post any other suggestions if you find a better solution to this problem though! :) Thanks

Comment: Sounds great. If you think this answered the OP, please mark it as the accepted answer later so other SO users with the same issue can find a solution easier :)

Comment: Can't seem to identify why it wouldn't work for more options unfortunately!

Comment: I've found why that's happening in ionic 2 docs, so I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, so long story short, there is no way we can do that for the moment?

Comment: If you want to show more than 6 options, then we should find a workaround (using CSS and events to hide the buttons on the alert, and close the alert as soon as you select any of the options).

Comment: We could easily do that indeed. How about getting the selection and updating the result in the ion-select field though?

Answer (score 6):

I know this thread is 7 months old and the OP is probably long past this question but since the feature is yet to be added to ionic framework, I'm adding the workaround I came up with for other people's reference.

**CSS PART**

Intuitively the first thing you need to do is to add some sass/css to hide the unwanted buttons. I did that by passing a css class "remove-ok" to `selectOptions` for my `ion-select` element. (I'm only removing OK button but if someone needs to remove cancel button as well, that's an easy css modification).

In component:

```
this.selectOptions = {
      cssClass: 'remove-ok'
    };
```

and in HTML:

```
<ion-select [selectOptions]="selectOptions">
```

And in `app.scss` add:

```
.remove-ok {
    .alert-button:nth-child(2) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**SCRIPT PART**

Now that the OK button is hidden, you will need to somehow close the alert view.

To invoke `click()` event on the hidden OK button is straightforward and intuitive but you'll soon find out that although it works perfectly on `ionic serve`, it won't work on an actual iOS device.

The solution is to find reference to the alert view, pass the checked option to the select handler, and finally dismiss the view.

So in `ngOnInit` in your component class, you'll need this:

```
ngOnInit() {
        let root = this.viewController.instance.navCtrl._app._appRoot;
        document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        let btn = <HTMLLIElement> document.querySelector('.remove-ok .alert-button-default:nth-child(2)');
        let target = <HTMLElement> event.target;
        if(btn && target.className == 'alert-radio-label')
        {
              let view = root._overlayPortal._views[0];
              let inputs = view.instance.d.inputs;
              for(let input of inputs) {
                if(input.checked) {
                  view.instance.d.buttons[1].handler([input.value]);
                  view.dismiss();
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
        });
    }
```

Again, if you intend to remove the Cancel button as well, mind the css references in this code.

Comment: Hi, This works great but i've found an issue with this. please check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635738/cannot-read-properties-input-of-undefined)

Comment: and also i'm getting the return value as an array instead of string?

Comment: on <ion-option (ionSelect)="changeOKButton()"/> I want to again change the css back to OK button But it's not working...

Answer (score 2):

**Implementation made in Ionic version 6.12.3:**

In your HTML create the `ion-select`. Add the attibute `[interfaceOptions]="randomOptions"`:

```
<ion-select interface="action-sheet" [interfaceOptions]="randomOptions" ngModel>
    <ion-select-option value="...">Option #1</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="...">Option #2</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

In your TS create a public variable with the exact name you gave in the HTML and add the options you intend for `ion-select`. Add the attribute `cssClass: 'randomCSSClassName'`:

```
public randomOptions: any = { 
    cssClass: 'randomCSSClassName',
    ...
};
```

For last, in your `global.scss` file just add a CSS class with the exact same name you gave in TS and just add the class `.action-sheet-group-cancel` with a `display: none`:

```
.randomCSSClassName {
    .action-sheet-group-cancel {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**This implementation was tested in Web, iOS and Android. It works perfectly!**

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure the dropdown options will be nicely centered on the screen along with radio buttons?

Comment: I am sure. By the date/ionic version that I implemented this solution, tested it and posted the answer, it's just like I previously said "This implementation was tested in Web, iOS and Android. It works perfectly!"

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have done the three steps you suggested and [here](https://ibb.co/HDJ4pXx) is an image of how the UI looks like once the dropdown menu is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Pass empty value :

```
<ion-select okText="" cancelText="">
      <ion-option>
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
```

It is working in my case.