# ionic 2 ion-select - close select box programmatically

Tags: ionic2

I'm working on ionic2 project.
I use ion-select element.

I search after a way to close the select-box programmatically on select any item (not wait the user to press OK).

```
  <ion-select id="select" #select>
      <ion-option (ionSelect)="closeAndSave()" *ngFor="let option of enumList" [value]="option">{{ option}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
```

`

```
class myClass{
    @viewChild('select') select:Select;
    closeAndSave(){
        /*it is come here on press any option. but how can I close here my select element? I tried: this.select.destroy()  - not do any thing. any solution?*/
    }
```

`

Comment: please give solution , how you solved it

Answer (score 7):

this is what I did:

```
this.court = val;
this.select.close();
```

put this inside your `closeAndSave` function.

Before that u need to pass some value from your closeAndSave function like:

```
(ionSelect)="closeAndSave('someValueHere')"
```

then use this value there in you TS code:

```
import { Select } from 'ionic-angular';

class myClass{
    @ViewChild(select) select:Select;
    closeAndSave(val){
    this.someVar = val;
        this.select.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i edit this question and : import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

Comment: you can use this template its a good sample https://stackoverflow.com/a/48656554/308578

Answer (score 1):

try to test this tag:

you only need to add **interface="action-sheet"** in the ion-select element.

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="action-sheet">
      <ion-option value="f" selected="true">Female</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

I'm not sure if that's a valid option (in terms of UX) in your app.

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39015858/308578

Comment: By far the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used this:
  (document.querySelector('ion-backdrop') as HTMLElement).click();

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this works, but it is shown as a popup and popups can be dismissed with the ionic ViewController.

You can use it like this:

```
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular'
...
export class YourComponent {
    constructor(private viewCtrl: ViewController){}
    closeAndSave(){
        //save things here 
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but not work... it dismiss the last page that push to the stack.