# How to pop out ion-select using different button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How do I pop out the ion-select using different button?

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="choices" multiple="true">
        <ion-option>Appliances</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Automobile</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Cellphones</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Clothing</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Computers</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Electronics</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Toys</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can `ViewChild` with `ionic-angular`

### html

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="choices" multiple="true" #mySelect>
     <ion-option>Appliances</ion-option>
     <ion-option>Automobile</ion-option>
     <ion-option>Cellphones</ion-option>
     <ion-option>Clothing</ion-option>
     <ion-option>Computers</ion-option>
     <ion-option>Electronics</ion-option>
     <ion-option>Toys</ion-option>
</ion-select>

<button ion-button (click)="openSelect()">Open</button>
<button ion-button (click)="closeSelect()">Close</button>
```

### ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,Content, Select } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage 
{    
    @ViewChild('mySelect') selectRef: Select;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public events: Events) 
    {}

    openSelect()
    {
        this.selectRef.open();
    }

    closeSelect()
    {
        this.selectRef.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The clearest and simplest example i have found so far. It made my code working. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you.!

Comment: thanks but when we have more that one select element in a page for others did not work what is your opinion?

Comment: @PareshGami yes exactly but my second element seems load data after init.? what about it? can you help me or send an article or StackOverflow link? (ionSelect) for that not worked! how can I add event listener programmatically after data initiated? in this example https://stackoverflow.com/q/41237061/308578

Comment: @Paresh Gami will you please tell me same solution for ionic4?

Comment: @userI yes I am able to do it for ionic 4.

Comment: @userI You can check my medium blog here https://medium.com/@gamiparesh5/how-to-pop-out-ion-select-using-different-button-in-ionic-4-3e036f3f7ea3?sk=ffdb9166bd421bcf61ee0f56d2e7d35f

Comment: @Paresh Gami Im not able to close ion-select on button click because its not having method close

Comment: @userI If ion-select is open how you click close button? Because ion-select cover full area of device screen.

Comment: @Paresh Gami Im clicking mobile's hardware back button

Comment: @userI If we press the back button of hardware that ion-select close by itself

Comment: @Paresh Gami No its not closing ion-close itself .The ion-select remain as it is when press back button

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @PareshGami

But in ionic 4, if you want to display the list only if a `button` is clicked and hide `select`

1.Import `IonSelect`

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Events, IonSelect } from '@ionic/angular';
```

2.Inside class, add reference to `select` and set `showList` to true to hide `select`. Also add `setCountry()` to retrieve selected country.

```
@ViewChild('countryList') selectRef: IonSelect;
showList = true;

setCountry() {
    console.log('New country');
}
```

3.In HTML, add `select` element with hidden property

```
<ion-select placeholder="Country" #countryList [hidden]='showList' (ionChange)='setCountry()'>
    <ion-select-option value="1">Egypt</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="2">Kuwait</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="3">UAE</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="4">Qatar</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="5">Bahrain</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="6">Saudi Arabia</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>

<ion-label (click)='displayCountry()'>Change</ion-label>
```

So `select` element is invisible and clicking `Change` will display the country list to select.

Comment: Have you any idea how to set interface in above your code.?
I mean set interface=popover.

Answer (score 2):

The code below works.

In template (HTML)

```
<ion-button (click)="openSelectList()"></ion-button>
 <ion-select #countryList (ionChange)='setCountry($event)' hidden="true">
    <ion-select-option value="1">Egypt</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="2">Kuwait</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

In .ts

```
@ViewChild('countryList') selectRef: IonSelect;
   ...

   openSelectionList() {
     setTimeout(()=>{
       this.selectRef.open();
     }, 2);
   }

   setCountry(event) { console.log('Selected country is ', event.detail.value) }
```