# How to remove the cancel and ok buttons in dropdown using ionic2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am new to the ionic.At first i had created the dropdown,Inside the dropdown there is some value,when the user clicks some value in the dropdown it will automatically display cancel and ok button but i should not want to display the cancel button,instead of that if user selects some value in the dropdown,it should go to same page.

Below is the screenshot i had got:

[image]

Comment: You want to display only the `OK` button or remove all buttons? Your title and description are not matching

Comment: @Huiting when ever we select radio button,it automatically get that value close the drop down.We want to remove completely OK&CANCEL button.

Comment: @Huiting we dont want multiple selections in the single drop down, so we want to remove the OK&CANCEL button.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014520/ionic2-ion-select-without-ok-and-cancel

Comment: Using radio alert should not allow multiple selections. Only checkbox alert would allow

Comment: @Huiting checkbox also should not display

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135546/discussion-between-krishna-32-and-huiting).